# Number as a std::string or double?

Tags: c++, string, parameters

I'm writting a C++ library for http clients. I don't have much experience with programming, so please help me.

I have method named `add`. It gets two parameters. The first is name of type and second is parameter q. It is a number between 0 and 1 <0,1>. It should have 0 to 4 digits after dot.

I can write it but I don't know what's the better:

1. `void add(std::string type, double q)` -> I must convert q to std::string in body of this method.
2. `void add(std::string type, std::string q)` -> It's ok, it's faster but maybe less intuitive for user, because it's a number (?)....

Is it a good idea, to have two methods: 1) and 2)?

Please help me. I don't have an experience... I know that two of this methods works but what is better, more popular. What do You think? How would you write this?

Comment: Could you give a concrete example, to make things clearer? I.e. is it something like `add("hello",7.51104421)` giving `hello_7.5110` as output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you want to make it clear what is expected of the user simply by them taking a look at the method signature. Your code should provide helpful hits to the person who is using it (i.e. make it more obvious what your code is doing and what's expected of them).

Let's start with the worst one:

```
void add(std::string type, std::string q)
```

- There is nothing making it clear that `q` is supposed to be a number.
- `q` is not a very descriptive name.

With the above example, the caller may get confused and call the method with reversed parameters: `add("5.0123", "someType")` There is nothing telling the user that they did something wrong, until the parameters have to be used. The worst part is that you don't know where things will blow up now. This may result in some very difficult to track down bugs simply because the proper type wasn't enforced.

Slightly better:

```
void add(std::string type, double q)
```

- Now it's clear that the user is adding a type and the double value of some sort.
- `q` is still not a descriptive name

**I would recommend:**

```
void add(std::string type, double value)
```

- Now it's clear that the user is adding a type and the double value of some sort.
- The parameter name of the double is now `value` (which is more descriptive than `q`).

Now the user can't call the method with the parameters out of order, i.e. `add(5.0123, "someType")`, as it would result in a compiler error. If it's not obvious: it's MUCH better to get a compiler error, because it can be fixed immediately. This way you're making safer code from the ground up.

This, of course, means that you'll have to convert the `double` to a `string`, but *for the most part* it's a small price to pay given all the benefits outlined above.

I don't know what the value represents, but the more closely you can name the parameter to the "real-world" entity it represents, the better it is.

Comment: Perfect answer.  It's also worth pointing out that in all likelihood whoever was using this library would probably have to convert from a numeric type to a string anyway, so doing it inside the function is simply saving the user from having to do this themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what the method is supposed to do and how users will call it. If the second parameter is a number, then you should use an appropriate numeric type. In general, you should write code in whatever way seems more "natural". The above post by Link is great and goes into a lot more detail about this.

As for your concern about what's "faster" you need to **stop** thinking about that. These sort of micro-optimizations are unlikely to have a measurable impact on performance and they are not something you should be worried about as a new programmer. Focus on *correct* code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two interleave problems here:

1. The floating point types `float`, `double`, and `long double` cannot represent decimal numbers exactly, even if the decimal numbers have only a few digits. For example, when representing `0.1` as one of these type, you'll get a rounded value. The standard library makes sure that when you read this value and write it again, you get back the original value (except for trailing zeros: `0.1000` may get formatted as `0.1`). For formatting the rounding error isn't much of a problem but the moment you start doing arithmetic the small error can cause interesting problems. Passing around an exact representation, e.g. a `std::string`, has the advantage that a function processing these values can do the Right Thing.
2. The problem of using `std::string` instead of a numeric value has the problem that the interface doesn't indicate what the argument represents and the compiler can't help with getting the argument straight using type checking: The actual type is hidden within a `std::string`. Ideally, you would use an argument which retains the value exactly while also indicating its semantics.

Depending on your needs, using a floating point type or a `std::string` may be the right choice: If you want to pass the numeric values through your function and it is acceptable to loose trailing fractional digits, it is probably best to use a floating point type. If you need to exact arithmetic and need to retain trailing factional zeros, a `std::string` may be the better choice. Preferably, you'd use a type dedicated to the correct representation of decimal values, though (in the future you are hopefully able to use [`std::decimal64`](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3407.html) but it isn't, yet, part of the standard).